# How to call jQuery in joomla on specific script

Tags: jquery, javascript

I' m trying to use jQuery contextMenu within a joomla 3 site.
The basic jquery code for the menu is:

```
 $(function() {
    $.contextMenu({
        selector: '.context-menu-one', 
        callback: function(key, options) {
            var m = "clicked: " + key;
            window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m); 
        },
        items: {
            "edit": {name: "Edit", icon: "edit"},
            "cut": {name: "Cut", icon: "cut"},
           copy: {name: "Copy", icon: "copy"},
            "paste": {name: "Paste", icon: "paste"},
            "delete": {name: "Delete", icon: "delete"},
            "sep1": "---------",
            "quit": {name: "Quit", icon: function(){
                return 'context-menu-icon context-menu-icon-quit';
            }}
        }
    });
```

I load jquery framework with `JHtml::_('jquery.framework');` I replaced `$function` with `jQuery(function(){`.

How may I change $.contextMenu so that it is acceptable by Joomla? I tried many changes but I get $.contextMenu is not a function.

I also tried to use `JHtml::_('jquery.framework',false);` so that to use $ instead of (jQuery) but still not acceptable.

If I include jquery library from a cdn and use $ instead of (jQuery) it works fine but this way I' m getting conflicts with other extensions that use jquery.

Comment: jQuery contextMenu is a plugin? Are you sure you are loading the plugin and after the jQuery library and that your javascript is running after all these have been loaded in the page?

Comment: In fact i'm trying to use http://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo.html it is a jquery library. Everything is loaded.

Comment: Any link to the page with the problem?

Comment: Try this: replace `jQuery(function(){` with `jQuery(function($){`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the $ - sign inside your jQuery function, you have to call it like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
   $.contextMenu({ ...
```

(Note the $ inside of function())

$ is just a shortcut often used for jQuery. In Joomla we have the problem that it often conflicts with other JavaScript libraries, like Mootools for example.

You could also call it like that:

```
jQuery(function() {
   jQuery.contextMenu({ ...
```

If you still get the error than probably the plugin is loaded before jQuery library. How do you add the plugin?

Comment: Yes! This was the answer. The first one worked. Thank you very much